# E-commerce with asp.net mvc (E-mail sending error)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, e-commerce

i am trying to do e-commerce site with asp.net mvc. When i enter address info and then click complete order after i select the products. It should send me an e-mail that shows the order details. I get the e-mail but after clicking complete order i get an error like below. Actually it should say your order has been sent successfully. How can i solve this? Some of sites say that your mvc and your server are not compatible. Thanks,

[Here is the error photo](https://i.hizliresim.com/m28opV.png)

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

i solved it. The problem occured because of the route of the view. Thanks,

Comment: Suggest you delete this and your question. Its of no use to anyone else (and then spend some time reading the [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help) files to understand how to ask a question and answer one)